# Adding DATEADD to a SUBSTRING OF TEXT to get a date in the future

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, dateadd

I am attempting to pull out a date from a substring of a text field that includes 'x' number of metadata such as company name, currency etc that is all input to one field with a nodeID as an identifer e.g.

Column name - Attributes
Values look like this:
Company Name27/04/2021... and so on.

I need to pull the Date within the A61 field only then add on a dateadd for anything that has a date greater than but not greater than 3 months on from this date.

This is also joined to a separate table that holds a 'Filename' column that is linked to that date.

This is the current, incorrect code that I am using but it is obvious I need to work on this.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!
`SELECT DISTINCT n.Filename
  , SUBSTRING ('<A61>', 6,5) + SUBSTRING ('<A61>', 11,5)AS ExpiryDate
  FROM NODE n
  JOIN NODEMETADATA m 
  ON n.MetaID = m.MetaID
  WHERE SUBSTRING ('<A61>', 6,5) + SUBSTRING ('<A61>', 11,5) = DATEADD(MONTH, 3, GETDATE())
  AND n.NODETYPE = 9`

There are no error messages but the results do not contain anything within and including the 3 months as my DATEADD is seemingly only going to pull anything that is exactly 3 months after.

Due to this I am also unsure if the DATEADD is correctly working on the substring and treating the substring as a combined date.

SSMS 2008

Sample data for specific Cell:

```
<A4>Company name</A4></A5><A61>27/04/2021</A61><A9>VAT</A9>...and so on
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.  Do you realize you are passing a string of length 6 to `substring()` and then looking for the 11th position?  The question really doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to convert the string to a date...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes sorry I was looking at how I would SELECT a SUBSTRING then also filter on that same substring to include the DATEADD and that was what I came up with as I was aware you can't pull multiple results from a single substr? Sorry if I am incorrect.

I see someone has included the tag now so I'll remember that in future.

How would I include sample data I thought I mentioned that the column includes an unspecified number of 'nodes' that begin and end with, for instance, <A61> xxxx </A61> but seems this must have been removed by myself accidentally, sorry!
Sample data included